# Rails omniauth-saml + devise + ADFS issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin, omniauth, adfs3.0

I am trying to integrate our ADFS login with our application which uses ActiveAdmin in combination with Devise. I succesfully added omniauth-saml for that purpose. The application now redirects to ADFS, the login succeeds but than fails on the callback. I get the error `Invalid ticket`.

When I try to look into the response on the server in the omniauth-saml lib I can see it says: `@document=<UNDEFINED> ... </>` and `@decrypted_document=<UNDEFINED> ... </>`

The `initializers/devise.rb` reads:

```
config.omniauth :saml,
                assertion_consumer_service_url: 'https://my_server/admin/auth/saml/callback',
                issuer: 'https://my_server/',
                authn_context: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport',
                idp_sso_target_url: 'https://my_adfs_server/adfs/ls/',
                assertion_consumer_service_binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
                assertion_consumer_logout_service_binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
                idp_sso_target_url_runtime_params: {original_request_param: :mapped_idp_param},
                name_identifier_format: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress',
                idp_cert: idp_certificate,
                request_attributes: {},
                attribute_statements: {email: ['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress'],
                                       name: ['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name'],
                                       first_name: ['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname'],
                                       last_name: ['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname']},
                private_key: sp_key,
                certificate: sp_certificate,
                security: {authn_requests_signed: true,
                           logout_requests_signed: true,
                           logout_responses_signed: true,
                           metadata_signed: true,
                           digest_method: XMLSecurity::Document::SHA1,
                           signature_method: XMLSecurity::Document::RSA_SHA1,
                           embed_sign: false}
```

How can I solve this?

**Addition:**
It appears that REXML::Document is unable to decrypt the Cypher inside of the SAML response. It fails to do so without errorring. When I try to do it myself by using https://www.samltool.com/decrypt.php I see no problems with it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I picked the wrong certificate from ADFS metadata xml. Need to pick the signing, not the encryption certificate.

Found this by using https://www.samltool.com/validate_response.php for debugging.

Comment: How I eventually fixed it can be found on my blog: http://www.michaelsommer.nl/2016/06/implementing-single-sign-on-with-adfs.html